# Read from linux web camera using OpenCV

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, v4l2, v4l

I'm trying to read raw video from web camera connected to my linux machine. I'm using OpenCV and l4v2 library (gstreamer).
Here are some details on my camera:

```
root@blah:~$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
        Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: ''
        Name        : e436eb7d-524f-11ce-9f53-0020af0

        Index       : 2
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'RGB3' (emulated)
        Name        : RGB3

        Index       : 3
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'BGR3' (emulated)
        Name        : BGR3

        Index       : 4
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'YU12' (emulated)
        Name        : YU12

        Index       : 5
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'YV12' (emulated)
        Name        : YV12
```

Here is my super simple code:

```
VideoCapture capture = VideoCapture(0);
if (!capture.isOpened()) {
      // Error in opening the video input
      cerr << "Unable to open video file for read: " << FLAGS_in_video << endl;
}
else {
  cout << "Opened video for read: " << FLAGS_in_video << endl;
}
```

And here is output and error I get:

```
Trying to open device 0 to read.
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP
mmap: Invalid argument
Opened video for read: 0
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
```

I've built OpenCV with WITH_V4L and WITH_LIBV4L flags ON.

I'd appreciate any help or advise on how to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out eventually - I had LP_PRELOAD which forced l4lib being loaded instead of l4v2.